# How to set jqplot donut chart colours per slice with multiple rings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm trying to set the colors to a jqplot donut chart with multiple rings. I need that each slice be filled with a specific color like the example below:

[image]

I read in the documentation that I need to set the "*varyBarColor*" to **true**, and use "*series*" with  an array of many "*seriesColors*" however it only shows the default colors.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var s1 = [['a',8], ['b',12]]; 
var s2 = [['a',3], ['b',17]]; 
var s3 = [['a',6], ['b',14]]; 
var s4 = [['a',10], ['b',10]]; 
var s5 = [['a',2], ['b',18]];

var plot4 = $.jqplot('divId', [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5], {
    seriesDefaults: {               
        series: [
            {seriesColors: [ "#8156a1", "#000"]},
            {seriesColors: [ "#418cc8", "#ec79c0"]},
            {seriesColors: [ "#ec79c0", "#f69c44",]},
            {seriesColors: [ "#f69c44", "#fadb48"]},
            {seriesColors: [ "#fadb48", "black"]}
        ],
        renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,            
        rendererOptions:{        
            sliceMargin: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,        
            startAngle: 90,
            showDataLabels: false,
            shadowAlpha: 0,     
            ringMargin:2,               
            varyBarColor: true,             
            thickness: 7                
        }
    },
    grid: {         
        background: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        shadow: false,
        drawGridLines: false,
        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: '0'
    }
});
```

Any idea on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem, (a very stupid one in fact). The series value should be outside of seriesDefaults, not inside like I was doing it:

```
var plot4 = $.jqplot('divId', [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5], {
series: [
    {seriesColors: [ "#8156a1", "#000"]},
    {seriesColors: [ "#418cc8", "#ec79c0"]},
    {seriesColors: [ "#ec79c0", "#f69c44",]},
    {seriesColors: [ "#f69c44", "#fadb48"]},
    {seriesColors: [ "#fadb48", "black"]}
],
seriesDefaults: { 
    renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,            
    rendererOptions:{        
        sliceMargin: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,        
        startAngle: 90,
        showDataLabels: false,
        shadowAlpha: 0,     
        ringMargin:2,               
        varyBarColor: true,             
        thickness: 7                
    }
},
grid: {         
    background: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    shadow: false,
    drawGridLines: false,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: '0'
}
```

});